# Excel - Possible to create a sorted view of a column in one sheet on another sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm trying, in Excel 2007, to populate a column in one sheet with the data contained in a column on another sheet, so that I may provide another sorting on the data, related to that sheet only.

I've tried to boil it down to being able to have a column on sheet2 automatically being populated with all rows from a column in sheet1, but I can't seem to do so.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to use MS Query to query the data from the first sheet.

When you create a data source, select MS Excel data source and browse for your file. I believe you will have to name the data range from the source sheet to be able to query it.

Answer (score 0):

On sheet 1 you have your data sorted by one column.
On sheet 2 you want the same data sorted by another column instead.
It's not clear if you only want to bring across one column or more than one.

You can't just use =A2, =A3, =B2 =B3 etc then sort as this will not work.

One option might be a simple pivot table with row headings but no data values, and sort that field in the PivotTable.

Alternatively, if the field you want to sort on is numeric you might be able to do this by using RANK to work out the order, then a lookup function to pull the data across in RANKed order. More info would help work out if this is an option

Answer (score 0):

Can you just do a Paste Special > Paste Link whenever there are additions or deletions to the source data? The linked data will automatically reflect *changes* to the source, so it's only additions and deletions that are problematic. (And actually, deletions just give you a "#REF!" error, which --depending on how you use the data-- you may be able to ignore via the `IsErr()` function.)